# Exchange 2003 Event ID 9337 - Offline Address Book

Tags: exchange-2003

I have a support issue with an Exchange 2003 SP2 server.

Event ID: 9337
Description:
OALGen did not find any recipients in address list '\Global Address List'.  This offline address list will not be generated. 
- Default Offline Address List

When you preview the Global Address list within Exchange Systems Manager all is fine.
Turning off cached mode on Outllok clients still errors

- Public fiolders / System folders are fine
- OABINTEG detects no issues, Pfdavadmin has checked all DACL
- The GAL and OAB have been deleted / recreated several times (With differnt names)
- DCDIAG, NETDIAG, ExchangeBPA all run without error

Exhausted Google links diagnosing this issue, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, Exchange has run into problems building the Offline Address Book for the Global Address List. Maybe this will help:

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=905482

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb125107(EXCHG.65).aspx

If you set diagnostic logging on the Exchange server for the MSExchangeSA\OAL Generator to maximum you should get more in depth Events logged which may help determine what the problem is.